# Spring MVC 3 Mapping

Tags: spring-mvc, url-routing, spring-3

This may seem simple, but not yet found a solution.
How to map to my applications www.mysite.com.br/MyController instead of www.mysite.com.br/servlet-name/MyController.

Thanks

Comment: make changes in your 'servlet-api'

Comment: Could you give me an example or a link about it? Thanks!

Comment: 'servlet-name' might be your context root, which may be set on your application server rather than in your code. It depends on your server. Which server are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're using Tomcat, you probably need to set your context root to be the default for your server.

If your application is configured in *server.xml* then this means you set the *path* attribute  on `<Context>` to an empty string, ie "".

```
<Context docBase="webapps/MyWAR" path=""></Context>
```

See http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/config/context.html

There are other ways of setting the path attribute if you're running Tomcat in an IDE, for example directly from Eclipse. In Eclipse you set the path attribute in the *Modules* tab on the server window.